# Data access layer using Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, design-patterns

I am building a c# - linq - sql server winforms/asp.net application, accessing a database. I would like my business logic layer to be easily testable, and that means not littering it with Linq database queries everywhere. What design patterns/ best practices are available for the following use cases 
- inserting/updating a new object
- searching for an object
- loading a bunch of related data into a sort of "presentation" object that could be displayed by various views ?

Comment: Do you mean Linq to SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Repository Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/linqrepository.aspx) is the one I think you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

Here is a six part article about [Architecting LINQ To SQL Applications](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/03/09/previous-architecting-linq-to-sql-applications-part-5.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I recomend to view video lessons http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos#ASP.NET%20MVC%20Storefront%20Starter%20Kit Part 1-3 about services/repositories/filters. It's good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Look into putting your database calls into a set of classes implementing a common interface (Repository pattern is a common way to do this).  Then you can mock these objects when running tests.  Just make sure the repositories themselves are tested somewhere too :)